# Peoplesoft Component Interface

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine, peoplecode

Im working on Component Interface in Psoft using AE and Pcode.

Upon create() method for keys an error shows

ERROR : 
Invalid value for key with Prompt table in Search Edit. (91,78)

Does anyone have a big knowledge in peoplesoft specially in component interface.
Please help thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to be more specific to get good answer. Please read help center how to ask section.

Comment: Hello @MehmetSunkur 

This is what I need to do.

I need to insert data from v 8.x to 9.x using Component Interface. Component Interface already exist in ptools.

Data of 8.x added to schema PRODXX

Answer (score 0):

> Upon create() method for keys an error shows
>
> ERROR : Invalid value for key with Prompt table in Search Edit. (91,78)

1. Identify the component used by your Component Interface (can be seen in PeopleTools Application Designer by opening the Component Interface. It will be in the top left position of the left Component Interface pane.) [image]see [PeopleBooks](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26239_01/pt851h3/eng/psbooks/tcpi/chapter.htm?File=tcpi/htm/tcpi03.htm)
2. Identify the Search Record used by your Component (can be seen in PeopleTools Application Designer by opening the Component, opening Definition Properties, and opening the "Use" tab to see the Search Record [image] see [PeopleBooks](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55243_01/pt854pbr0/eng/pt/tapd/task_SettingComponentProperties-0774bd.html#topofpage) "Use Properties" on "Setting Component Properties")
3. Identify the keys on the Search Record by opening the Record in Application Designer and using the Record Toolbar to see the Record in "Use Display" mode. [image] see [PeopleBooks on Record Definitions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13292_01/pt849pbr0/eng/psbooks/tapd/chapter.htm?File=tapd/htm/tapd09.htm)
4. On same search record from #3 above, switch to "Edits Display" mode to see the prompt table for each key. [image]
5. Using information gleaned from steps #3 and #4, double-check the values you are passing in to your create statement to make sure they conform the the field definitions (length, data type) and prompts (list of acceptable values)